# Problems making Carmen Robotics toolkit in Fedora

Tags: makefile, fedora, robotics, carmen

I'm running into issues installing the Carmen Robotics toolkit in Fedora;

### Making:

When I type `make`, I get the following error message

```
---- Copying global/carmen-std.ini to carmen.ini 

   ***********
   E X P O R T
   ***********

---- Copying ipc.h to [path]/carmen-0.7.4-beta/include/carmen
```

... many similar lines

```
---- Copying param_interface.h to [path]/carmen-0.7.4-beta/include/carmen
Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make: *** [export] Error 255
```

I've googled around and saw that this can be caused by spaces instead of tabs at the beginnings of lines. There is no such issue anywhere near line 7 of the makefile.
Doing make -d gives a lot of output, which ends with:

```
Updating goal targets.... Considering target file `export'.  
File `export' does not exist.  
Finished prerequisites of target file `export'.  
Must remake target `export'.  
Invoking recipe from ../Makefile.rules:285 to update target `export'.  
Putting child 0x174b8e0 (export) PID 5816 on the chain.  
Live child 0x174b8e0 (export) PID 5816  
Reaping winning child 0x174b8e0 PID 5816  
Live child 0x174b8e0 (export) PID 5819  
Reaping winning child 0x174b8e0 PID 5819  
Removing child 0x174b8e0 PID 5819 from chain.  
Successfully remade target file `export'.  
GNU Make 3.82 Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu Copyright (C) 2010  
Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+:  
GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>  
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  
Reading makefiles...  
Reading makefile `Makefile'...   
Reading makefile `../Makefile.conf' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...  
Reading makefile `../Makefile.vars' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...  
Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.  
Reaping losing child 0xda4940 PID 5794   
make: *** [export] Error 255  
Removing child 0xda4940 PID 5794 from chain.
```

I've heard that getting to Carmen to compile can be a terrible experience, but I didn't expect that it would give me *this* much trouble, especially since I'd done it successfully on another computer in the past.

***I can't even make clean***

Does anyone have sage wisdom to offer on this topic?

Comment: Solved one problem
> Searching for linux kernel headers... not found
The problem here was that 
a) --headers didn't seem to be working.
I edited the config file to point to /usr/src/kernels/$DISTRO/include/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded from Make 3.82 to 3.81 and this issue went away.